# how to print the first element of a json array in powershell?

Tags: powershell

When I execute the following script:

```
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path "addresses.csv"

$newCsvData  = foreach($row in $csvData){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        name  =  $row.name
        lastname  =  $row.lastname
    }
 }

# Format the CSV data to JSON
$jsonData = $newCsvData | ConvertTo-Json


Write-Host $jsonData[0]
```

I only get

```
[
```

but if I print `Write-Host $jsonData` I see that the entire array is there:

```
[
    {
        "name":  "John",
        "lastname":  "Doe"
    },
    {
        "name":  "Jack",
        "lastname":  "McGinnis"
    },
    {
        "name":  "John \"Da Man\"",
        "lastname":  "Repici"
    },
    {
        "name":  "Stephen",
        "lastname":  "Tyler"
    },
    {
        "name":  "",
        "lastname":  "Blankman"
    },
    {
        "name":  "Joan \"the bone\", Anne",
        "lastname":  "Jet"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps confusingly, [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.3) converts to a string representation of json. 
The documentation states:

> The ConvertTo-Json cmdlet converts any .NET object to a string in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

and

> You can then use the ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet to convert a JSON-formatted string to a JSON object, which is easily managed in PowerShell.

So you should do:

```
$jsonData = $newCsvData | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host $jsonData[0]
```